# Why is my gulpfile causing only a sporadic css inject?

Tags: sass, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

The following gulp tasks work for some css files, but not for others.
My global styles are injected on save as desired, but my roadmap.css file is not (needs a hard refresh).

How could I debug/solve this?

```
var settings = {
...
  sass_files: "applications/**/*.sass",
  css_files: "applications/**/*.css"
...

  }

var public_dir = "dist/"

gulp.task('build-sass', function() {
  return gulp.src(settings.sass_files)
    .pipe(changed(public_dir, { extension: '.css' }))
    .pipe(sass({
      errLogToConsole: true,
      includePaths: [
        "applications/_shared_assets/vendor/bootstrap-sass",
        "applications/_shared_assets/vendor/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets",
        "applications/_shared_assets/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap-sass-custom",
        "applications/_shared_assets/vendor/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets",
        "applications/_shared_assets/features",
        "applications/_shared_assets/css"
      ]
    })
  )
    .pipe(prefix(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(public_dir))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
});

gulp.task('build-css', ['build-sass'], function() {
  return gulp.src(settings.css_files)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(public_dir))
});

gulp.task('css-rebuild', ['build-css'], function() {
});


gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function() {
...
  gulp.watch(settings.sass_files, ['css-rebuild']);
...
});
```

The page for which the global styles are properly injected, and for which the roadmap file is not.

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="portfolioroadmap.css")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="../_shared_assets/css/global_styles.css")
```

These are both generated by build-sass.
I'd love any help, been stuck on this for hours now.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, although browsers are not sensitive to upper/lowercase: gulp is.

Make sure the reference in the .html has the same case as the filename in your filesystem (it was portfolioroadmap.css in my case rather than PortfolioRoadmap.css).